# Subset columns of sparse eigen matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I want to take subset columns of some sparse matrix (column-major)
As far as i know there are [indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) stuff in Eigen.
But i cannot call it for sparse matrix:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> m;
std::vector<int> indices = {1, 5, 3, 6};
// error: type 'Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>' does not provide a call operator
m(Eigen::all, indices);
```

Is there are any workaround?

UPD1
Explicitly specified that columns can be in arbitrary order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Sparse matrices do not provide that API as they also only provide some block operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SparseMatrix actually does not provide any `operator()`, so this cannot be done.

EDIT: The following was aimed at an older version of the question.

In case your actual use case also has the property that the columns you want to access are adjacent you can instead use

```cpp
SparseMatrix<double,ColMajor> m(5,5);
int j = 1;
int number_of_columns=2;
m.middleCols(j,number_of_columns) = ...;
```

There are also `m.leftCols(number_of_columns)` and `m.rightCols(number_of_columns)`
These are even writable, because the matrix is column-major.

All other block expressions are defined but read-only, see [the corresponding Sparse Matrix documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title7).

EDIT: To answer the updated question:
I guess you won't be able to avoid copying. With copying it can be done like this (not tested)

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> m;
std::vector<int> indices = {1, 5, 3, 6};
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> column_subset(m.rows(),indices.size());
for(int j =0;j!=column_subset.cols();++j){
column_subset.col(j)=m.col(indices[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, @Eike! Unfortunately, i need to subset columns in arbitrary positions, not adjacent. Sorry for badly stated question, i'll update it.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. I guess the only way is to copy the columns into a new sparse matrix. I have updated the answer in that regard.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just checked your solution, and it works! Only problem is indices(j) -> indices[j] typo. Thank you for help!

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the correction! I tend to use Eigen::Vector for everything (if I don't need the reserve functionality of `std::vector`), because I compile with warnings forbidding implicit sign conversion and then the hassle of casting from `size_t` to `Eigen::Index` or back is a bit much.