# How to roll the rows of a Eigen:Matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I want to reindex a `Eigen:Matrix` by rolling `N∈ℤ` rows like this (here `N=+1`):

```
1 4 7  ->  3 6 9
2 5 8      1 4 7
3 6 9      2 5 8
```

Is there a simple way, or do I have to create a new matrix and copy over the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up a new matrix and copying the data. Eigen's block operations allow doing this in an efficient way. Here is how a shift by `n` rows can be done for the example above.

```
MatrixXi A(3,3);
A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
A.transposeInPlace();
int n = 1; // number of shifts
n = n % A.rows();

MatrixXi B(A.rows(), A.cols());
B.bottomRows(A.rows() - n) = A.topRows(A.rows() - n);
B.topRows(n) =  A.bottomRows(n);

std::cout << "B = " << B << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a matlab-like syntax you can also use

```cpp
MatrixXd A;
//... fill A
VectorXi indices = {{2,0,1}};

A(indices, Eigen::all);
```

I don't know, whether this internally makes a copy.

Note: This does not work for Sparse matrices, see [Subset columns of sparse eigen matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70953755/subset-columns-of-sparse-eigen-matrix/71025516?noredirect=1#comment125650316_71025516)

Comment: Interesting, I also thought about using arithmetic sequences, but unfortunately I'm <Eigen 3.4 (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html )

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it. What keeps you from upgrading Eigen, as it is Header-only?